# warning message when calling a class member function inside another as a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, stdthread

I have a class and it contains multiple methods. My requirement is to call one of the member function inside another as a thread.

```
Class ApplicationManager
{
   ....
   ....
   void method();
   void test(std::string arg1, std::string& arg2);
};

void ApplicationManager::method()
{
   std::string arg, arg2;
   ....
   ....
   std::thread(&ApplicationManager::test, this, arg, arg2);
}
```

When I compile the above, I getting below warning message. Since it is too big, I am unable to get what it tries to say. Copied warning message below.

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(16707566): warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from '_Ty' to 'std::string &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::basic_string,std::allocator>
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(16707566): note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(16707566): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Invoker_pmf_pointer::_Call<_Ty,ApplicationManager*,std::basic_string,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>(_Decayed,_Ty1 &&,std::basic_string,std::allocator> &&,std::basic_string,std::allocator> &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=void (__cdecl ApplicationManager::* )(std::string,std::string &),
            _Decayed=void (__cdecl ApplicationManager::* )(std::string,std::string &),
            _Ty1=ApplicationManager *
        ]

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(237):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::invoke,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>(_Callable
>   &&,ApplicationManager
>   *&&,std::basic_string,std::allocator>
>   &&,std::basic_string,std::allocator>
>   &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Callable=void (__cdecl ApplicationManager::* )(std::string,std::string &)
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(246):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2,3>(std::tuple,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3>)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>,
>               _Ty=size_t
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(245):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2,3>(std::tuple,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3>)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>,
>               _Ty=size_t
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(242):
>   note: while compiling class template member function 'void
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept'
>           with
>           [
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(230):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept'
>   being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thr/xthread(257):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\thread(46):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_Launch,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>(_Thrd_t
>   *,_Target &&)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=std::tuple,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,
>               _Target=std::unique_ptr,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>,std::default_delete,std::allocator>,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>>>
>           ] ....\Sources\ApplicationManager.cpp(3856): note: see reference to function template instantiation
>   'std::thread::thread(_Fn
>   &&,ApplicationManager *&&,std::string &,std::string &)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Fn=void (__cdecl ApplicationManager::* )(std::string,std::string &)
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\filesystem(2392):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::chrono::time_point'
>   being compiled C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(616):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::basic_string_view>' being
>   compiled C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2124):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::is_convertible>>' being
>   compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _StringViewIsh=const wchar_t *
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2122):
>   note: see reference to variable template 'const bool
>   conjunction_v > >,std::negation > >' being compiled C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2281):
>   note: see reference to alias template instantiation
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>::_Is_string_view_ish<_StringViewIsh>'
>   being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _StringViewIsh=const wchar_t *
>           ]*

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/kK7Mth Please edit your post to include a [mre].

Comment: @aschepler I edited my post. my second argument is a reference.

Comment: @cigien can you point me the issue exactly :(

Comment: This appears to be an msvc extension. gcc and clang don't even compile [this](https://godbolt.org/z/NeKHvR), when a member function argument is an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

your function

```
test(std::string arg1, std::string& arg2);
```

takes a reference as a second argument but here

```
std::thread(&ApplicationManager::test, this, arg, arg2);
```

it takes a value not a reference, hence you have to modify this to

```
std::thread(&ApplicationManager::test, this, arg, std::ref(arg2));
```

to wrap a reference to your variable in a reference wrapper object. [see](https://godbolt.org/z/YgAc9b)

Note that the compiler message you've posted is specific to MVC compiler but your code doesn't compile (before editing) with gcc or clang as cigien has mentioned.